# How to forward http requests from one server to another server using spring boot?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, oauth, influxdb

**Why would I want to do this?**

I installed [influxDb](https://influxdb.com/) on AWS and I want to be able to call it from outside. I mean from another server not on AWS. The problem is that I need to secure everything that is exposed to the web with OAuth and influxDb does not support it. My idea is to build a small server that would be secured by OAuth, check if the incoming http request is from a validated user. If it is it would then call the influxDb and return the result.

**What I need to do**

I already know how to secure a spring boot app with OAuth. All I need to do now is to route all the incoming requests to another server.

**Here is an example:**

- application A is outside AWS
- application B is the proxy on AWS
- application C is internal on AWS (can only be accessed by AWS instances)

This is what I have in mind.

```
A calls B:
POST https://ip.of.B:8083/api/metric?access_token=A5ghj12JHYX2355JJ

B routes the calls to C without OAuth: 
POST https://ip.of.C:8083/api/metric
```

Comment: setup a dns name for C and just have the proxy look it up (and cache it).